# 15.04 Swap won't "stay decrypted" (both Disk and Home Directory encrypted)

Tags: encryption, 15.04, swap

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04.  During installation, I enabled both full disk encryption and home directory encryption.  I then proceeded to install several applications.

While installing these with apt-get, I got the following message:

```
Broadcast message from root@my-machine (Thu 2015-06-11 20:46:43 EDT):

Password entry required for 'Please enter passphrase for disk ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (cryptswap1) on none!' (PID 7634).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!

Please enter passphrase for disk ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (cryptswap1) on none!
```

This message came up fairly randomly, averaging once every minute or so.  A couple times it happened twice in a row, with virtually no time between (I suppose there's a chance I typed my password wrong).  The installation process appeared to pause each time (until I enter my passphrase), though I'm not convinced it was fully paused.

To me, it appears that my machine isn't saving the decryption passphrase, which I think it should do at boot (when I decrypt the disk) or at login time (when I decrypt the home folder).  **Any idea how I can coax it into doing this automatically?**